# T-SQL infinite update in cursor with variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cursor that updates a table's records to convert an image to `varbinary(max)`. On the cursor I'm updating all the records in the table, according to the ID_FOTO column, with the statement: `WHILE (@ID_FOTO <= @ID_FOTO_MAX)`

However, when it reaches the last ID, it keeps updating (only the last record as below) and never stops.
So it keeps updating, and doesn't stop with the final ID of the table.

Cursor:

```
DECLARE @ID_FOTO INT;
DECLARE @CD_ARQUIVO VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR (4000);
DECLARE @ID_FOTO_MAX INT;

SET @ID_FOTO_MAX = (SELECT MAX(ID_FOTO) AS ID_FOTO FROM D_GB_FOTOS);

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_FOTO, CD_ARQUIVO, (NM_DIRETORIO + '\' + NM_FOTO + TP_EXTENSAO) AS CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY FROM D_GB_FOTOS WHERE LINORIGEM <> 'CARGA MANUAL';
OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ID_FOTO, @CD_ARQUIVO, @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY

WHILE (@ID_FOTO <= @ID_FOTO_MAX) BEGIN
    SET @tsql = 'UPDATE D_GB_FOTOS ' +
                'SET CD_ARQUIVO = (SELECT CD_ARQUIVO from Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY + ''', Single_Blob) CD_ARQUIVO)' +
                ' WHERE D_GB_FOTOS.ID_FOTO = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO) + ';'  
    PRINT ('ID_FOTO: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO))
    PRINT ('ID_FOTO_MAX: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO_MAX))
    PRINT ('SELECT STATEMENT: ' + @tsql)
    EXEC  (@tsql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID_FOTO, @CD_ARQUIVO, @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Output from `Print`:

> (1 row affected) ID_FOTO: 6529 ID_FOTO_MAX: 6531
>
> (1 row affected) ID_FOTO: 6530 ID_FOTO_MAX: 6531
>
> (1 row affected) ID_FOTO: 6531 ID_FOTO_MAX: 6531
>
> (1 row affected) ID_FOTO: 6531 ID_FOTO_MAX: 6531
>
> (1 row affected) ID_FOTO: 6531 ID_FOTO_MAX: 6531

Where's the error?

Comment: At a guess the last fetch from the cursor is going to fail, because there will be no records in it, which might set `@ID_FOTO` to null and then the compare fails. You normally check `@@FETCH_STATUS` when looping on a cursor, that way you can detect when all records have been processed.

Comment: You still need to check for the `@@FETCH_STATUS`. Add to the `While`, `AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`. This should stop the cursor loop.

Comment: @SS_DBA it worked! I added to the `While` and it stoped in the last ID!! Post your answer so I can check as correct, please. But what I could understand is, if I'm saying that the cursor should run from 1 to 10 for example, why was updating the number 10 infinite? I said where it should have stopped. But really thanks for your answer.
@DaleK Thank you as well for the tip.

Comment: It becomes infinite because null values never meet the compare operator, null can only be detected by `IS NULL` never by -, <, > etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are not looking for the end of the cursor. You still need to check for the `@@FETCH_STATUS`. Add to the `While`, `AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0`. This should stop the cursor loop.

```
DECLARE @ID_FOTO INT;
DECLARE @CD_ARQUIVO VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY VARCHAR(4000);
DECLARE @tsql NVARCHAR (4000);
DECLARE @ID_FOTO_MAX INT;

SET @ID_FOTO_MAX = (SELECT MAX(ID_FOTO) AS ID_FOTO FROM D_GB_FOTOS);

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_FOTO, CD_ARQUIVO, (NM_DIRETORIO + '\' + NM_FOTO + TP_EXTENSAO) AS CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY FROM D_GB_FOTOS WHERE LINORIGEM <> 'CARGA MANUAL';
OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @ID_FOTO, @CD_ARQUIVO, @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY

WHILE (@ID_FOTO <= @ID_FOTO_MAX AND @@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    SET @tsql = 'UPDATE D_GB_FOTOS ' +
                'SET CD_ARQUIVO = (SELECT CD_ARQUIVO from Openrowset(Bulk ''' + @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY + ''', Single_Blob) CD_ARQUIVO)' +
                ' WHERE D_GB_FOTOS.ID_FOTO = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO) + ';'  
    PRINT ('ID_FOTO: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO))
    PRINT ('ID_FOTO_MAX: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@ID_FOTO_MAX))
    PRINT ('SELECT STATEMENT: ' + @tsql)
    EXEC  (@tsql)
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @ID_FOTO, @CD_ARQUIVO, @CD_ARQUIVO_VARBINARY
END

CLOSE cur    
DEALLOCATE cur
```